# Game of Life - Basic Java GUI Implementation

Tags: java, game-of-life

I've been working on a basic implementation of Conway's Game of Life over the last day, and I've just finished a 'playable' version.

If anyone has the time, would you mind making any suggestions on code improvements that I can make?

Thanks!

**GameOfLife.java**

```
package robbie.gameoflife.main;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import robbie.gameoflife.cells.Cell;
import robbie.gameoflife.cells.CellManager;

public class GameOfLife {

    private static final String TITLE = "Game of Life";

    public static final int CELL_SIZE = 10, CELL_AMOUNT = 50;
    public static final int WIDTH = CELL_SIZE * CELL_AMOUNT, HEIGHT = WIDTH;

    public static final Dimension DIMENSIONS = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    private static final boolean RUNNING = true;

    public static final Cell[][] CELLS = new Cell[CELL_AMOUNT][CELL_AMOUNT];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
        frame.setSize(DIMENSIONS);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        GameCanvas canvas = new GameCanvas();
        frame.add(canvas);
        canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);

        loadCells();

        CELLS[10][10].setAlive(true);
        CELLS[10][11].setAlive(true);
        CELLS[10][12].setAlive(true);
        CELLS[11][10].setAlive(true);
        CELLS[12][10].setAlive(true);
        CELLS[12][11].setAlive(true);
        CELLS[12][12].setAlive(true);
        CELLS[11][12].setAlive(true);

        startGameLoop(canvas);
    }

    private static void loadCells() {
        for (int x = 0; x < CELLS.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < CELLS[x].length; y++) {
                if (CELLS[x][y] == null)
                    CELLS[x][y] = new Cell(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void startGameLoop(GameCanvas canvas) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        if (RUNNING) {
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    CellManager.updateCells();
                    canvas.repaint();
                }

            }, 1000, 1000);
        }
    }

}
```

**GameCanvas.java**

```
package robbie.gameoflife.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import robbie.gameoflife.cells.Cell;

public class GameCanvas extends Canvas {

    public GameCanvas() {
        super();

        this.setSize(GameOfLife.WIDTH, GameOfLife.HEIGHT);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics graphics = this.getGraphics();
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, GameOfLife.WIDTH, GameOfLife.HEIGHT);
        Random random = new Random();
        graphics.setColor(new Color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat()));

        for (Cell[] cells : GameOfLife.CELLS) {
            for (Cell cell : cells) {
                if (cell.isAlive()) {
                    int size = GameOfLife.CELL_SIZE;
                    int x = cell.getX() * size;
                    int y = cell.getY() * size;

                    graphics.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Cell.java**

```
package robbie.gameoflife.cells;

public class Cell {

    private int x, y;
    private boolean alive = false;

    public Cell(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return alive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean alive) {
        this.alive = alive;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void toggleAlive() {
        this.alive = !this.alive;
    }

}
```

**CellManager.java**

```
package robbie.gameoflife.cells;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import robbie.gameoflife.main.GameOfLife;

public class CellManager {

    public static ArrayList<Cell> getNeighbourCells(Cell cell) {
        ArrayList<Cell> neighbourCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        int cellX = cell.getX();
        int cellY = cell.getY();

        for (int x = cellX - 1; x <= cellX + 1; x++) {
            for (int y = cellY - 1; y <= cellY + 1; y++) {
                if (x < 0 || x >= GameOfLife.CELL_AMOUNT || y < 0 || y >= GameOfLife.CELL_AMOUNT)
                    continue;

                Cell neighbourCell = GameOfLife.CELLS[x][y];
                if (neighbourCell.equals(cell))
                    continue;

                if (neighbourCell.isAlive())
                    neighbourCells.add(neighbourCell);
            }
        }

        return neighbourCells;
    }

    public static int getNeighbourCount(Cell cell) {
        return getNeighbourCells(cell).size();
    }

    public static void updateCells() {
        ArrayList<Cell> deadCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        ArrayList<Cell> aliveCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

        for (Cell[] cells : GameOfLife.CELLS) {
            for (Cell cell : cells) {
                int neighbourCount = CellManager.getNeighbourCount(cell);
                if (neighbourCount < 2 || neighbourCount > 3)
                    deadCells.add(cell);
                else if (cell.isAlive() && (neighbourCount == 2 || neighbourCount == 3))
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                else if (!cell.isAlive() && neighbourCount == 3)
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
            }
        }

        for (Cell cell : aliveCells)
            cell.setAlive(true);

        for (Cell cell : deadCells)
            cell.setAlive(false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Prefer interfaces to implementations

> ```
>     public static ArrayList<Cell> getNeighbourCells(Cell cell) {
>         ArrayList<Cell> neighbourCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
> ```

and

> ```
>         ArrayList<Cell> deadCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
>         ArrayList<Cell> aliveCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
> ```

You never use `ArrayList` specific functionality though, just `List` functionality (`add` and implicitly the `iterator`).

If you make these

```
    public static List<Cell> getNeighbourCells(Cell cell) {
        List<Cell> neighbourCells = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
        List<Cell> deadCells = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Cell> aliveCells = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can change implementations by simply changing the right side.

Note that the `<>` syntax only works in newer versions of Java.

#### Prefer doing it right to checking if right

> ```
>         int cellX = cell.getX();
>         int cellY = cell.getY();
> ```

```
        for (int x = cellX - 1; x <= cellX + 1; x++) {
            for (int y = cellY - 1; y <= cellY + 1; y++) {
                if (x < 0 || x >= GameOfLife.CELL_AMOUNT || y < 0 || y >= GameOfLife.CELL_AMOUNT)
                    continue;
```

You can simplify this with `Math.min` and `Math.max`.

```
        int startX = cell.getX() - 1;
        int startY = cell.getY() - 1;

        int maxX = Math.min(startX + 2, GameOfLife.CELL_AMOUNT);
        int maxY = Math.min(startY + 2, GameOfLife.CELL_AMOUNT);

        for (int x = Math.max(startX, 0); x <= maxX; x++) {
            for (int y = Math.max(startY, 0); y <= maxY; y++) {
```

Now we don't check nine times (including once with the original values) if the `x, y` pair is in bounds (four checks per pair).  We only check each boundary once (four boundaries).

#### The `continue` is unnecessary here

> ```
>                 Cell neighbourCell = GameOfLife.CELLS[x][y];
>                 if (neighbourCell.equals(cell))
>                     continue;
> ```

```
                if (neighbourCell.isAlive())
                    neighbourCells.add(neighbourCell);
```

While the early bailout is often helpful, I'm not sure that I'd do it here.  Consider

```
                Cell neighbourCell = GameOfLife.CELLS[x][y];
                if (!neighbourCell.equals(cell) && neighbourCell.isAlive()) {
                    neighbourCells.add(neighbourCell);
                }
```

Since that's now the entire body of the loop, we don't need to `continue`.

I also added `{` and `}` because I prefer to always use the block form.  There's a set of problems that can arise with inattentive editing of the statement form that don't bother the block form.  I just find it easier to always use it.  The maintenance cost is cheaper in my opinion.

#### Don't Repeat Yourself

> ```
>                 if (neighbourCount < 2 || neighbourCount > 3)
>                     deadCells.add(cell);
>                 else if (cell.isAlive() && (neighbourCount == 2 || neighbourCount == 3))
>                     aliveCells.add(cell);
>                 else if (!cell.isAlive() && neighbourCount == 3)
>                     aliveCells.add(cell);
> ```

This is the same thing as

```
                if (neighbourCount < 2 || neighbourCount > 3) {
                    deadCells.add(cell);
                } else if (cell.isAlive()) {
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                } else if (neighbourCount == 3) {
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                }
```

The `else` statement lets you know that the expression in the `if` is not true.  You don't have to check it again.  So we know there are 2 or 3 neighbors in the first and we know that the cell is alive in the second (and we still know that there are 2 or 3 neighbors, although that doesn't help since 2 and 3 neighbor cells have different behavior when not alive).

WE can continue to simplify:

```
                if (neighbourCount < 2 || neighbourCount > 3) {
                    deadCells.add(cell);
                } else if (cell.isAlive() || neighbourCount == 3) {
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                }
```

Given that what you are doing is setting the alive status, we can do even better in terms of efficiency.

```
                if (neighbourCount < 2 || neighbourCount > 3) {
                    deadCells.add(cell);
                } else if (!cell.isAlive() && neighbourCount == 3) {
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                }
```

Now the second `if` only puts the cell in the list if it is not alive but should be next round.  We can do the same thing to the first `if`.

```
                if (cell.isAlive() && (neighbourCount < 2 || neighbourCount > 3)) {
                    deadCells.add(cell);
                } else if (!cell.isAlive() && neighbourCount == 3) {
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                }
```

But now we call `cell.isAlive()` twice, once in each branch.  This makes the `else` redundant.  We could just as well write

```
                if (cell.isAlive() && (neighbourCount < 2 || neighbourCount > 3)) {
                    deadCells.add(cell);
                }

                if (!cell.isAlive() && neighbourCount == 3) {
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                }
```

or

```
                if (cell.isAlive() && neighbourCount != 2 && neighbourCount != 3) {
                    deadCells.add(cell);
                }

                if (!cell.isAlive() && neighbourCount == 3) {
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                }
```

This takes the negation of the or expression so that we can do without the extra parentheses.

Or even

```
                if (cell.isAlive()) {
                    if (neighbourCount != 2 && neighbourCount != 3) {
                        deadCells.add(cell);
                    }
                } else if (neighbourCount == 3) {
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                }
```

Although the complexity of nesting might make it less readable.  I would consider any of these last three to be reasonable.

Note that even in your original, there was a case, `!cell.isAlive() && neighbourCount == 2` that doesn't get set either way.  This just makes that clearer.

#### Naming

Also consider changing `deadCells` and `aliveCells` to something that makes it clearer that the status is changing, e.g. `dyingCells` and `birthingCells`.  Otherwise, you could just write

```
                if (neighbourCount == 3 || (neighbourCount = 2 && cell.isAlive())) {
                    aliveCells.add(cell);
                } else {
                    deadCells.add(cell);
                }
```

This sets every cell's status explicitly.

A bit wasteful though, as the majority of cells will not be alive and not be changing status.